# MongoDb - make the value of a particular field, a field in the returning document along with the count

Tags: mongodb

Suppose i have the following collection. It can have more documents with different 'item' list in 'items' and having different 'type'.

```
[
  {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "@pid": "131",
          "text": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "61",
          "text": "Mango"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "92",
          "text": "cherry"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "27",
          "text": "grape"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "34",
          "text": "dragonfruit"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "@pid": "131",
          "text": "Apple"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "27",
          "text": "grape"
        },
        {
          "@pid": "34",
          "text": "dragonfruit"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "items": {
      "item": [
        {
          "@pid": "131",
          "text": "Apple"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "A"
  }
]
```

Now, if i what to get the following document for `'items.item.text' : {$regex:'Apple|Mango}'`

```
[
    {
        "item" : "Apple",
        "count" : {
            "A" : "2",
            "B" : "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "item" : "Mango",
        "count" : {
            "A" : "1"
        }
    }
]
```

since 'apple' occurs in type 'A' twice and in 'B' once; and 'mango' occurs in only 'A', once.

Can we write such kind of a query? I tried using the aggregation pipeline but couldn't figure out the exact query.

**EDIT** : A format similar to the one below will also be fine :

```
[
    {
        "Apple" : {
            "A" : "2",
            "B" : "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "Mango" : {
            "A" : "1"
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks a lot in advance.